# get the value of the <doc> xml element to use in query

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code

```
 $xml = $mbpay->processPaymentInfo();
 Log::info('Showing $mbpay:' . var_export($xml, true));
```

The log shows like:

```
[2018-07-06 12:40:56] local.INFO: Showing $mbpay: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<getmb_id>
 <status>ok</status>
<!---->
 <doc>000...</doc>
</getmb_id>'
```

With this xml, I want to get from the `notifications` table the value of the column "`r_id`" where the value of the "`doc`" column is equal to the "doc" element of the `$xml` above.

Do you know how to properly get the value of the  xml element so is possible to do the query to get the `r_id`?

The query should be something like "        `$rID = Notifications::where('doc', $doc)->pluck('r_id')->first();`
" but how to get the `$doc`?

updated:

```
    $mbpay = new MBPay($payment_info);

    $processed_payment = $mbpay->processPaymentInfo();
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($processed_payment);
    $doc = $xml->doc;

    $rID = DB::table('notifications')->where('doc', $doc)->pluck('r_id')->first();

    Log::info('Showing $mbpay: ' . var_export($xml, true));
    Log::info('doc: ' . var_export($doc, true)); // shows SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
))
    Log::info('rID: ' . var_export($rID, true)); // shows NULL
    Log::info('xml: ' . var_export($xml, true));

    return \Response::make($xml, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

The `$mbpay->processPaymentInfo()` shows like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<getmb_key>
     <status>ok</status>
     <message>...</message>
     <user>...</user>
     <doc>...</doc>
</getmb_key>
```

Comment: https://php.net/simplexml is a good and easy start. That could get you the value under `<doc>` which you could then use to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you will only ever expect one doc node, there are a few ways you can go about getting the value of the  node. The first thing that comes to mind is `simplexml_load_string()`:

```
$processed_payment = $mbpay->processPaymentInfo();
$xml = simplexml_load_string($processed_payment);
$doc = (string) $xml->doc;
```

We can also parse it with [DOMDocument's loadXML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php):

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($processed_payment);
$docs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('doc');
$doc = $docs->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

As well as with [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)::

```
$element = new \SimpleXMLElement($processed_payment);
$doc = (string) $element->doc[0];
```

Finally, there's good old regex with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$result = preg_match("/<doc>(.*?)<\\/doc>/", $processed_payment, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Which method you use depends on the structure of your document and, somewhat, your personal preference. For me, `simplexml_load_string()` was the first thing that came to mind, but after considering alternatives and given the knowledge of the expected structure, I think I'd prefer `SimpleXMLElement()`.

[Here are working examples of each method above.](https://repl.it/@shawnlindstrom/ExaltedAdequateBetaversion)

Comment: Thanks, but like that " $processed_payment = $mbpay->processPaymentInfo();
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($processed_payment);
        $doc = $xml->doc;

        $rID = DB::table('notifications')->where('doc', $doc)->pluck('r_id')->first();". It appears that rID is NULL. Do you know why?

Comment: The issue should be because $doc shows "SimpleXMLElement::__set_state(array(
))  ".

Comment: Does the <doc> node returned from $mbpay->processPaymentInfo() contain a value? Does the actual XML structure differ from the example you provided?

Comment: Yes it has a vallue, $processed_payment shows like "<getmb_id>
                 <status>ok</status>
                 <user>...</user>
                 <doc>...</doc>
               </getmb_id>' ".

Comment: Try grabbing the XML and test getting the doc node in isolation. If <doc> is not a direct child of <getmb_id>, you'll need to traverse the node. Use arrow notation to do so. For example, if the strucutre looks like this<getmb_id><parent><doc>000</doc></parent></getmb_id> , you'd use (string) $xml->parent->doc to get the value of the doc node. If this isn't the case and <getmb_id> has no parent and <doc> is a child of <getmb_id>, I'm at a loss without being able to see the actual structure returned from $mbpay->processPaymentInfo().

Comment: Thanks, the doc is a direct child so I dont know why it appears empty. I update the question with the xml of "$mbpay->processPaymentInfo()".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174537/discussion-between-shawn-lindstrom-and-john).